# Using hash of password to encrypt private key

Tags: security, encryption, hash

I am developing a web application in which I need to encrypt sensitive information. My plan is to use use AES-256 where the private key is encrypted by a hash of the user's password.  I need to store the hash of the password for authentication purposes, but it obviously can't be same used to encrypt the private key. My current thought is to use bcrypt to generate a key to be used to encrypt the private key. For authentication, my thought was to simply hash the password using bcrypt and then hash that hash using bcrypt again and then store that hash in the database. Since it is one way, there shouldn't be any way to use the stored hash to decrypt the private key? Are there any obvious security issues with doing this that I may be missing?

My other thought was to use two different encryption algorithms, such as using a bcrypt hash to encrypt the private key and storing a SHA-2 hash for authentication purposes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If no one here can give you a definite answer, you may want to try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

don't use hash to encrypt AES password. salted hash should be used only for authentication. when user logs in, you have his password. use this password to encrypt (first time) and decrypt (later) the AES key and then forget the password.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) in this situation. You can use two different salts, one that would derive the symmetric key and the other one would derive the password hash to be stored. The salt should contain a deterministic part distinguishing the two different use cases, as well as a random part - cf. this comment:

> Otherwise, the salt should contain data that explicitly
> distinguishes between different operations and different key
> lengths, in addition to a random part that is at least eight
> octets long, and this data should be checked or regenerated by
> the party receiving the salt. For instance, the salt could have
> an additional non-random octet that specifies the purpose of
> the derived key. Alternatively, it could be the encoding of a
> structure that specifies detailed information about the derived
> key, such as the encryption or authentication technique and a
> sequence number among the different keys derived from the
> password.  The particular format of the additional data is left
> to the application.

A plain, salted SHA-2 probably isn't enough because of the poor entropy of typical passwords, as was mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: use two different salts.  When the user enters their password concatenate it with a random salt and hash it for the password recognition routine.  Use a *different* salt and hash it again for the AES encryption key.  Depending on how secure you want things, you can stretch the hashing as well.

Effectively you have:

```
storedPasswordCheck = SHA256(password + salt1);

AESkey = SHA256(password + salt2);
```

The AES keys are not stored of course, but are regenerated from the user's password as needed.  You will need two separate salts, best at least 128 bits each, stored for each user.

Comment: (Sorry for deleted comment, I misread your answer; +1) -- but I would mention that applying the hash transform to the source password does not grant you any more security than you would obtain by using the user's password directly in the hash. That is, the hashing function cannot generate more entropy than was in the user's origonal password. (This applies to any hashing function)

Comment: I almost don't even think you need the salt on the AES key -- the password still isn't kept in plain text either way.

Comment: Passwords are not always secure, users tend to pick something they can remember.  A salted, hashed (and possibly stretched) password is going to have fewer weaknesses.  For security, slight overkill is not a bad thing.

Comment: How does it have fewer weaknesses? Salting is to make it hard to recover the password from the hash. But the hash isn't being stored here, it's only being used as the input to AES.

Comment: People will choose guessable passwords: "secret", qwertyuiop", "password123".  They will also pick memorable passwords, which are vulnerable to trying all the words in a dictionary.  There are password password cracker programs which exploit these vulnerabilities.  A hash prevents that, and the salt prevents the easy use of pre-prepared rainbow tables and other off-line attacks.  Stretching slows down any attacker as much as you want to.

Comment: No, neither hashing nor salting prevent anything related to these common "stupid" passwords. No matter how well hashed or salted, if the password is vulnerable to a dictionary, it's going to be vulnerable. Salting prevents rainbow tables, which don't make sense against AES -- rainbow tables are for breaking hashes, not block cyphers. Hashing's advantage is that the cleartext password is not stored, but as the input to AES the cleartext isn't being stored anyway.

Comment: Thanks Billy and rossum for the comments. They were very helpful and really got me thinking about my approach. To provide some more background that may be helpful, I'm using PHP and planning on using mcrypt with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 for the encryption algorithm. From what I've read, in order to get the security of AES-256, you need a key that is 256 bits. Since a user's password may not be that long, I thought that hashing the password would give me the longer key and thus be more secure.